# Yii , Widgets, mysql db not selected

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, yii, widget

Trying to access our mysql db through a widget and I'm getting this error: db connection failed: No database selected
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Trying to access our mysql db through a widget and I'm getting this error: db connection failed: No database selected
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?php


 Yii::import('zii.widgets.CPortlet');

class Test extends CPortlet
{
    public $testVar;
    protected function renderContent()
    {
        $this->render('test');


       /* $result = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM sales_rep.full_name
        ORDER BY full_name ASC");
        if(!$result) {
                die("db connection failed: ". mysql_error());
        }
        echo $this->$result;
        */
    }
}

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin0");
    if(!$connection) {
            die("db connection failed: ". mysql_error());
    }

    $result = mysql_query(
            "SELECT * FROM sales_rep full_name
            ORDER BY full_name ASC");
            if(!$result) {
                    die("db connection failed: ". mysql_error());
            }
            echo $this->$result;


    $db_select = mysql_select_db("intranet",$connection);
    if(!db_select) {
            die("db connection failed: ". mysql_error());
    }

    $result = mysql_query("Select full_name FROM sales_rep");
    if(!$result) {
            die("db connection failed: ". mysql_error());
    }


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row[1]." ".$row[2]."<br>";
    }


    mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: Your issue is not related to Yii, but to the unsafe mysql_... code you are using, which goes against the practice recommended by frameworks like Yii.

Comment: @crafter - it's just for testing, thanks for the 'advice' and the votedown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yii you should maintain database configurations at main.php file located at protected/config folder.
Find the section bellow and add your configurations:

```
'components'=>array(
    [...]
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=[YOUR_HOST];dbname=[YOUR_DATABASE]',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin0',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
 [...]
```